# Minimize area of n-gon circumscribed around unit circle

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization, circles, polygons, geometric-inequalities

Given regular unit circle and a n-gon, circumscribed around this unit circle.
I need to minimize area of n-gon.

Also i need to find the limit of n-gon area with $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Intuitively i understand that n-gon must be regular for minimizing it's area, but how formally can i show that?

Also by intuition i now that in limit area of n-gon converges to a circle's area, but can't prove it formally.

Note: i'm trying to solve it with inequalities, without using derivatives

Comment: What is the area of the regular $n$-gon circumscribed about the unit circle?

Comment: You can express the area in terms of the central  angles subtended by the sides of the polygon.  (These sum to $2\pi$.)  To prove that the area is minimal, you might try showing that if two triangles have different central angles, you get a smaller answer if you replace each of them by the average angle.  This ought to be just trigonometry, I would think.  At least that proves that if there is a minimum, it's the regular $n$-gon.

Comment: @area is equal to S = $\frac{na}{2}$, where $a$ - side of the n-gon

Comment: Sure, but you have to compute $a$ in terms of $n$ for the formula to be useful.

Comment: Sure i have to, but idk how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I believe this argument is valid (by the less than
Hilbertian standard of rigour that seems to apply to arguments in
synthetic Euclidean geometry - that's a topic for another question),
it only proves that if an $n$-gon circumscribing a circle has
minimal area, then it must be regular.  It does not prove that a
regular $n$-gon circumscribing a circle has minimal area.  For a
modified argument that does prove this, see under the horizontal
line after Theorem 1.  Although I haven't deleted the
original argument (because I haven't found any errors in it), it can
now be skipped in its entirety.

---

### Old version

**Lemma 1.** In a triangle $LMN,$ let the bisector of the angle at $L$
meet $MN$ at $K.$ If $|LN| > |LM|,$ then $|KN| > |KM|.$

*Proof.* By Euclid I.18, the angle at $M$ is greater than the
angle at $N,$ therefore $\angle LKM > \angle LKN.$ Construct $H$ on
$LN$ such that $\angle LKH = \angle LKM.$ Then $\triangle LKH$ is
congruent to $\triangle LKM$ (**ASA**), therefore:
$$
\text{area } \triangle LKN > \text{ area } \triangle LKH =
\text{ area } \triangle LKM.
$$
But triangles $LKN$ and $LKM$ have the same height, therefore the
base of the first, $|KN|,$ must be greater than the base of the
second, $|KM|.$ $\ \square$

**Lemma 2.** Let $LHK$ be an isosceles triangle, with base
$HK.$ Let $G$ on $HK$ and $N$ on $HK$ produced be such that
$\angle HLG = \angle KLN.$ Then $|GN| > |HK|.$

*Proof.* Construct $M$ on $HK$ such that:
$$
\angle KLM = \angle HLG = \angle KLN.
$$
Then triangle $KLM$ is congruent to triangle $HLG$ (**ASA**),
therefore $|KM| = |HG|.$
In the triangle $LKN,$ side $LN$ is opposite the obtuse angle
$\angle LKN,$ therefore $|LN| > |LK| = |LH|.$ The segment $LG$ lies
inside one of two right-angled triangles, with equal hypotenuses
$LH$ and $LK,$ therefore $|LH| > |LG|.$ Because triangles $KLM$ and
$HLG$ are congruent (already proved), $|LG| = |LM|.$ Putting all of
this together:
$$
|LN| > |LK| = |LH| > |LG| = |LM|.
$$
Therefore Lemma 1 applies, giving $|KN| > |KM|,$ whence:
$$
|GN| = |HN| - |HG| = |HN| - |KM| > |HN| - |KN| = |HK|,
$$
as required. $\ \square$

**Lemma 3.** Let $\gamma$ be a circle. Let the tangents from an
external point $Z$ meet $\gamma$ at $A, C.$ Let $B$ be a third point
on $\gamma,$ restricted to lie on one of the two arcs determined by
$A, C$. Let the tangent at $B$ meet the tangents $ZA, ZC$ at $X, Y,$
respectively. Then the length $|XY|$ of the line segment $XY$ is
minimal when $B$ is midway between $A$ and $C.$

*Proof.* Let $O$ be the centre of $\gamma.$ Then $OX$ bisects
$\angle AOB,$ and $OY$ bisects $\angle BOC,$ therefore $\angle XOY$
has the constant value $\frac12\angle AOC.$ The altitude of the
triangle $XOY$ is also constant, being equal to the radius $r$ of
$\gamma.$
Construct an isosceles triangle $LHK$ with altitude $r$ and apex
angle $\frac12\angle AOC.$ This is congruent to the triangle $XOY$
when $B$ is at the midpoint of the arc $AC.$ For any other position
of $B$ on the arc, the triangle $XOY$ is congruent to a triangle
$GMN$ with the same apex $L,$ and base vertices $G,N$ satisfying
the conditions of Lemma 2, because $\angle GLN = \angle HLK.$
The conclusion of Lemma 2 therefore applies, so we have
$|GN| > |HK|.$ But the triangles were constructed so that
$|HK| = |XY|$ when $B$ is at the midpoint of the arc, and
$|GN| = |XY|$ when $B$ is in any position other than that.
$\ \square$

**Theorem 1.** Let $\gamma$ be a circle. Let $n$ be an integer
$\geqslant 3.$ Let $P$ be an $n$-gon circumscribed about $\gamma.$
Then the area of $P$ is minimal only if $P$ is regular.

*Proof.* The area of $P$ is $rs,$ where $r$ is the radius of
$\gamma$ and $s$ is the semiperimeter of $P.$ Minimising the area of
$P$ is equivalent to minimising $s$. Each vertex of $P$ contributes,
to the sum $s,$ the common length of the two tangents to $\gamma$
from that vertex. Therefore, if all but one of the $n$ points of
contact of $P$ with $\gamma$ are held constant, and the edge of $P$
that meets $\gamma$ at that one variable point is $XY,$ then the
total contribution to $s$ made by the vertices $X$ and $Y$ is equal
to $|XY|.$
If $P$ is not regular, then it has three successive points of
contact $A, B, C$ such that the arcs $AB$ and $BC$ are unequal. Let
$X, Y, Z$ be the points of intersection of the pairs of tangents at
$(A, B),$ $(B,C),$ $(A, C)$ respectively. $X$ and
$Y$ are successive vertices of $P.$ By Lemma 3, the length $|XY|$
is strictly greater than what it would be if $B$ were moved to the
midpoint of the arc $AC$ upon which it lies. Therefore the
semiperimeter of $P$ is not minimal, therefore neither is its area.
$\ \square$

---

### New version

**Lemma 4.** Let $B_1, B_2$ be points on an arc of a circle
$\sigma$ between rays $l, l'$ from the centre $O.$ For $i = 1, 2,$
let the tangent to $\sigma$ at $B_i$ meet $l$ at $X_i,$ and $l'$ at
$Y_i.$ If $\angle X_1OB_1 < \angle X_2OB_2,$ and if
$\angle X_1OB_1 + \angle X_2OB_2$ is strictly less than the angle
between $l$ and $l'$ - in particular, if $B_2$ lies at most halfway
around the arc between $l$ and $l'$ - then $|X_1Y_1| > |X_2Y_2|.$

[image: Lemma 4]

*Proof.* Construct the ray $l''$ through $O$ making an angle
equal to $\angle X_1OB_1$ with $OB_2.$ By the second hypothesis,
$l''$ lies between $l$ and $l'.$ For $i = 1, 2,$ let $l''$ intersect
$X_iY_i$ at $W_i.$ Let $X_1Y_1$ and $X_2Y_2$ intersect at $V.$
Because $OB_1$ and $OB_2$ are reflections of each other in $OV,$ the
tangents to $\sigma$ at $B_1$ and $B_2$ are reflections of each
other.  Because $l$ and $l''$ are also reflections of each other,
the points of intersection $W_2, W_1$ are reflections of $X_1, X_2$
respectively; therefore the triangles $VW_2W_1$ and $VX_1X_2$ are
reflections of each other.  But $\triangle VW_2W_1$ is strictly
contained in $\triangle VY_2Y_1.$ Therefore the area of
$\triangle VX_1X_2$ is strictly less than that of
$\triangle VY_2Y_1.$ Therefore the area of $\triangle OX_2Y_2$ is
strictly less than that of $\triangle OX_1Y_1.$ But both triangles
have altitudes equal to the radius of $\sigma.$ Therefore
$|X_1Y_1| > |X_2Y_2|.$ $\ \square$

**Lemma 5.** Let $\gamma$ be a circle. Let the tangents from an
external point $Z$ meet $\gamma$ at $A, C.$ Let $B$ be a point on
the shorter arc $AC$. Let the tangent at $B$ meet the tangents
$ZA, ZC$ at $X, Y,$ respectively.  Then the length $|XY|$ of the
segment $XY$ is least when $B$ is midway between $A$ and $C,$ and
increases strictly as $B$ moves from the midpoint towards $A$ or
$C.$

*Proof.* Let $O$ be the centre of $\gamma.$ Then $OX$ bisects
$\angle AOB,$ and $OY$ bisects $\angle BOC,$ therefore $\angle XOY$
has the constant value $\frac12\angle AOC.$ The altitude of the
triangle $XOY$ is also constant, being equal to the radius $r$ of
$\gamma.$

[image: Lemma 5]

Construct lines $l, l'$ meeting at angle $\frac12\angle AOC$ (i.e.
at an angle whose value is copied from $\frac12\angle AOC$ in the
present configuration) at the centre $O'$ of a circle of radius $r.$
Then the figure $OXBY$ is congruent to the similarly labelled figure
in Lemma 4, which traverses the circular arc from $l$ to $l'$ as the
present figure $OXBY$ traverses the arc $AC.$ Because both figures
occupy the midpoint position at the same time (so to speak), the
conclusion of Lemma 4 applies also to the present configuration.
$\ \square$

**Theorem 2.** Let $\gamma$ be a circle. Let $n$ be an integer
$\geqslant 3.$ Let $P$ be an $n$-gon circumscribed about $\gamma.$
Then the area of $P$ is minimal if and only if $P$ is regular.

*Proof.* The area of $P$ is $rs,$ where $r$ is the radius of
$\gamma$ and $s$ is the semiperimeter of $P.$ Minimising the area of
$P$ is equivalent to minimising $s$. Each vertex of $P$ contributes,
to the sum $s,$ the common length of the two tangents to $\gamma$
from that vertex. Therefore, if all but one of the $n$ points of
contact of $P$ with $\gamma$ are held constant, and the edge of $P$
that meets $\gamma$ at that one variable point is $XY,$ then the
total contribution to $s$ made by the vertices $X$ and $Y$ is equal
to $|XY|.$

If $P$ is not regular, then it has three successive points of
contact $A, B, C$ such that the arcs $AB$ and $BC$ are unequal. Let
$X, Y, Z$ be the points of intersection of the pairs of tangents at
$(A, B),$ $(B,C),$ $(A, C)$ respectively. $X$ and
$Y$ are successive vertices of $P.$ By Lemma 5, the length $|XY|$
is strictly greater than what it would be if $B$ were moved closer
to the midpoint of the arc $AC$ upon which it lies.

Mark the $n$ arcs between the $n$ points of contact of $P$ with $\gamma$
with a cyclic sequence of $n$ symbols $+, 0, -,$ one per arc, according as
the length of the arc is greater than, equal to, or less than $1/n$ of the
circumference of $\gamma.$ If $P$ is not regular, there must occur at least
one sequence consisting of a $+,$ followed by a possibly empty sequence of
$0$s, followed by a $-.$ Choose one such sequence.

Iteratively, modify $P$ by reducing the length of the first arc in the
sequence, which is marked with a $+,$ to $1/n$ of the circumference of
$\gamma.$ If the next arc in the sequence was a $0,$ it becomes the $+$
for the next iteration, and the numbers of $+, 0, -$ symbols in the
sequence remain unchanged.  Eventually we come to a sequence $+-,$ which
in the next step becomes either a $0+,$ a $00,$ or a $0-.$

Any such sequence of steps increases by either $1$ or $2$ the number of arcs
of length $1/n$ of the circumference of $\gamma$; thus eventually $P$ becomes
regular.

In any step in which a sequence $+0$ is replaced by $0+,$ the area of $P$
is unchanged.  There is at least one step in which a sequence $+-$ is
replaced by $0+,$ $00,$ or $0-.$ In each of those three cases, a point of
contact $B$ has been moved closer to the midpoint of the arc $AC$ on which it
lies. (In the case $00,$ $B$ becomes the midpoint.) By Lemma 5, therefore,
the semiperimeter $s,$ and therefore also the area of $P,$ has been made
strictly smaller.

Therefore, the area of the initial irregular circumscribing polygon
$P$ is strictly greater than that of some regular circumscribing
$n$-gon.  All regular circumscribing $n$-gons are congruent, by
rotation, therefore all have the same area.  Therefore, every
regular circumscribing $n$-gon has a strictly smaller area than
every irregular circumscribing $n$-gon.
$\ \square$

---

### A shorter, almost equally low-tech trigonometric proof, avoiding calculus

For $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n,$ let $\theta_i$ be half the angle subtended at
the centre of $\gamma$ by the arc between the $i^\text{th}$ and
$(i+1)^\text{th}$ points of contact of $P$ with $\gamma.$ (Addition of
indices $i$ is modulo $n,$ i.e. $i + n = i$ for all $i.$) Then:
$$
s = r(\tan\theta_1 + \tan\theta_2 + \cdots + \tan\theta_n).
$$

Let $M, m$ be indices such that
$\tan\theta_M = \max\{\tan\theta_1, \tan\theta_2, \ldots, \tan\theta_n\}$ and
$\tan\theta_m = \min\{\tan\theta_1, \tan\theta_2, \ldots, \tan\theta_n\}.$
Then $\tan\theta_M = \tan\theta_m$ if and only if $P$ is regular.

If $P$ is not regular, then $\theta_m < \pi/n < \theta_M.$ Define
$\theta_M' = \pi/n$ and $\theta_m' = \theta_m + \theta_M - \pi/n.$ Then
$\theta_M' + \theta_m' = \theta_M + \theta_m,$ and:
$$
0 < \theta_m < \min\{\theta_m', \theta_M'\} \leqslant \max\{\theta_m', \theta_M'\} < \theta_M < \pi/2.
$$

By an argument along the lines of Michael Rozenberg's first proof in his
answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3701223/if-0-alpha-alpha-delta-beta-frac-pi2-then-tan-alpha-tan-be) question:
$$
\tan\theta_M + \tan\theta_m > \tan\theta_M' + \tan\theta_m'.
$$
So if we replace $\theta_M, \theta_m$ with $\theta_M', \theta_m',$ and set
$\theta_i' = \theta_i$ for all $i \ne M, m$ (in essentially the same way as
in the synthetic proof above, where we used Lemma 5, instead of this
trigonometric inequality), we get a polygon $P'$ circumscribing $\gamma$
whose semiperimeter and therefore area are strictly less than those of $P.$

Because the number of values of $i$ such that $\theta_i' = \pi/n$ is at
least one more than the number of values of $i$ such that $\theta_i = \pi/n,$
this iterative process (which is a little simpler than the one described
before) terminates after at most $n - 1$ steps, yielding a regular
circumscribing polygon with an area strictly less than that of the initial
polygon $P.$ $\ \square$

Comment: I forgot that you also wanted to prove that the area of $P$ approaches the area of $\gamma$ as $n$ tends to infinity. You are really asking two questions in one, which is rightly frowned upon. I don't know if there's any natural way to merge an answer to the second question into my answer to the first question.

Comment: My exposition of the proof of Theorem 2 is almost certainly not very clear.  I plead exhaustion!  I will try to improve it tomorrow; and if I can't, I'll try to provide an illustrative diagram.

Comment: Ignore the part of the penultimate paragraph referring to a polygon $P'$; that's a hangover from the synthetic geometry proof. In the proof by trigonometry, it's just a matter of iteratively reducing the sum $\sum_i\tan\theta_i,$ while preserving the condition $\sum_i\theta_i = \pi.$

Answer (score 1):

Divide the circumscribed $n$-gon into $2n$ right triangles, each with one vertex at the center of the circle, one vertex at a vertex of the polygon, and the  third vertex at the point of tangency of a side of the polygon to the circle.
[image]

If the central angle in triangle $k$ is $\theta_k$, we have $0<\theta_k<\pi,\ k=1,\dots,2n, \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\theta_k=2\pi,$ and the area of the polygon is $$A:= \frac12\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\tan\theta_k$$

The area of the regular circumscribed $n$-gon is $$\frac{2n}2\tan\frac{2\pi}{2n} =\frac{2n}2\tan\left(\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\theta_k\right)\leq \frac{2n}2\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1{2n}\tan\theta_k=A,$$ where the inequality follows from the convexity of the tangent function on $[0,\pi/2).$

**NOTE**

I wasn't able to do this without appealing to convexity.  Without using convexity I was able to show that if a minimum exists, it is the regular $n$-gon, but I couldn't show existence, since the domain isn't compact.

Comment: @user Yes, you're right.  I was assuming that.

Comment: @user A correct proof is even simpler than the incorrect one.