# If $0 < \alpha < \alpha + \delta < \beta < \frac\pi2$ then $\tan\alpha + \tan\beta > \tan(\alpha + \delta) + \tan(\beta - \delta).$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, alternative-proof, karamata-inequality

For reasons that probably don't bear examination (I've rewritten my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3691445/minimize-area-of-n-gon-circumscribed-around-unit-circle) question, but I haven't posted the new improved version with added vitamins, because I wish to supplement my irritatingly long and pointless school-geometry proof with an equally quixotic school-trigonometry proof, avoiding the theory of convexity), I wish to prove:
$$
\text{If } 0 < \alpha < \alpha + \delta < \beta < \frac\pi2 \text{ then } \tan\alpha + \tan\beta > \tan(\alpha + \delta) + \tan(\beta - \delta)
$$
using only trigonometric identities familiar from secondary school mathematics.

All I have managed to come up with so far is this pathetic dog's dinner of a proof:

If $0 < \theta < \theta + \varphi = \frac\pi2,$ then
$$
\tan\theta + \tan\varphi = \tan\theta + \frac1{\tan\theta} = 2 + \left(\frac1{\sqrt{\tan\theta}} - \sqrt{\tan\theta}\right)^2,
$$
which decreases strictly with $\theta$ for $\theta \leqslant \frac\pi4.$

If $\alpha + \beta = \frac\pi2,$ then either $\alpha + \delta \leqslant \frac\pi4$ or $\beta - \delta \leqslant \frac\pi4,$ therefore $\tan\alpha + \tan\beta > \tan(\alpha + \delta) + \tan(\beta - \delta).$ $\ \square$

Assume from now on that $\alpha + \beta \ne \frac\pi2.$ Then $\tan\alpha\tan\beta \ne 1,$ and similarly $\tan(\alpha + \delta)\tan(\beta - \delta) \ne 1.$

Because $\alpha + \beta = (\alpha + \delta) + (\beta - \delta),$ the addition formula for the tangent function gives:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}\tag{$1$}
\frac{\tan(\alpha + \delta) + \tan(\beta - \delta)}{\tan\alpha + \tan\beta} =
\frac{1 - \tan(\alpha + \delta)\tan(\beta - \delta)}{1 - \tan\alpha\tan\beta}.
\end{equation}

Because $\tan\alpha\tan\delta < 1,$ we can write, after some tedious manipulation (yawn-making details provided on request):
$$
\tan(\alpha + \delta)\tan(\beta - \delta) - \tan\alpha\tan\beta =
\frac{\tan\delta(1 - \tan^2\alpha\tan^2\beta)[\tan(\beta - \alpha) - \tan\delta]}
{(1 - \tan\alpha\tan\delta)(1 + \tan\beta\tan\delta)}.
$$
Therefore $\tan(\alpha + \delta)\tan(\beta - \delta) - \tan\alpha\tan\beta$ has the same sign as $1 - \tan\alpha\tan\beta.$

It follows that the right hand side of \eqref{eq:1} is always strictly less than $1,$ and we are done (more like done in!). $\ \square$

Surely it must be possible to do better than this? Please put me out of my misery, so that I can be rid of this stupid obesssion, and perhaps even get on with some slightly more respectable mathematics instead!

Comment: You can just show that the function $f(\delta) = \tan(\alpha+\delta) + \tan(\beta-\delta)$ decreases in your specified integral by taking derivative. Based on my experience of dealing with these kind of stuff from contest questions, I am not sure if it gets much simpler whilst only using basic trigs.

Comment: Oh yes, I know it's trivial using calculus - I should have mentioned I was avoiding that, not just the theory of convexity.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be a heck of a lot neater to write $\gamma = \frac{\alpha + \beta}2$ and prove that $\tan(\gamma + \varepsilon) + \tan(\gamma - \epsilon)$ decreases strictly with $\varepsilon,$ but I really need to go for a long walk and forget about this for an hour or so!

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that if $\{a,b,c,d\}\subset\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, $a\geq b$, $c\geq d$, $a\geq c$ and $a+b=c+d$ so
$$\tan{a}+\tan{b}\geq\tan{c}+\tan{d}.$$
Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$\frac{\sin(a+b)}{\cos{a}\cos{b}}\geq\frac{\sin(c+d)}{\cos{c}\cos{d}}$$ or
$$\cos(c+d)+\cos(c-d)\geq\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)$$ or
$$a-b\geq c-d$$ or
$$a-c\geq b-d,$$ which is obvious because $a-c\geq0$, but $b-d\leq0.$

I think it is better to use Karamata.

Indeeed, if $\beta-\delta\geq\alpha+\delta$ so 
$$(\beta,\alpha)\succ(\beta-\delta,a+\delta).$$
If $\beta-\delta\leq\alpha+\delta$ so 
$$(\beta,\alpha)\succ(\alpha+\delta,\beta-\delta).$$
In any case your inequality follows from Karamata because $\tan$ is a convex function on $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$

Comment: The required inequality is actually *equivalent* to the convexity of the tangent function on $\left(0, \frac\pi2\right)$ (unless I've screwed up - I'll check), but I said I was avoiding the theory of convexity.

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley I added something. See now.

Comment: (+1) That looks delightful, thank you! I'll check it properly when I get back from my walk. I'll also look up that Karamata thing you mention.